# How can i upload image file from React to Rails api server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, multipartform-data, rails-api

I need to upload an image of my user from my react app to Rails api only server.

My HTML input file

```
<input ref={(input) => this.profileImage_input = input}
       type="file"
       name="user-profile-image"
       className="small-font-size"
       onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
```

So this is my component upload function.

```
let profileUploadImage = this.profileImage_input.files;
let user_info = {};

user_info = {
                username: this.username_input.value,
                profile_image: profileUploadImage
            };

this.props.update_user_with_image_server(user_info,this.props.user.user.id)
```

My actionCreator

```
export function update_user_with_image_server(user_info,user_id){

    let formData  = new FormData();

    for(let key in user_info) {
        if(user_info.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            formData.append(key, user_info[key]);
        }
    }

    return function (dispatch) {
        fetch(deafaultUrl + '/v1/users_profile/' + user_id,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                method: "PATCH",
                body: formData
            })
            .then(function(response) {

                if (response.status >= 400) {
                    throw new Error("Bad response from server");
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(json){

            });
    }
}
```

My rails user controller

```
  def update_with_image
    user = current_user
    if user.update_attributes(user_update_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
      render json: user, status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  private

  def user_update_params
    params.permit(:username,:profile_image)
  end
```

So the problem is it seems like `user_update_params` didn't workout rails cannot read the data and update in correctly so how could i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Since activestorage was announced today, I hope someone can answer this so I can do the same in my own app.